# Google Maps Screen Bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

To get the bounds of a screen over a region of Google Maps someone pointed me at this code from an old thread.

`mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds`

But when going through the reference online I can't find getVisibleRegion() any longer.  Was it deprecated and should I use

`mMap.getbounds()`

instead or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `getProjection()` method of GoogleMap returns an instance of `Projection` class.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection()

Projection class has `getVisibleRegion()` method as you can see in the reference documentation:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection

I hope this helps!